# Requiring unknown module Object.assign, with ReactNativeTextComponent in the stack trace

Tags: react-native

I upgraded to the latest react-native (0.23.1) and started getting the error:

[image]

I keep getting this error even after downgrading, so not sure if react-native is the cause, or another dependency I have. I could not find this error message by searching Google.

I also tried installing `npm install object-assign` and that did not help.

I am running babel preset `babel-preset-react-native-stage-0`.

Comment: I see Object.assign was removed in a commit made a few days ago: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/cb5d37713f381aa8e57e9b314c03a25a2e11796b, hopefully it's fixed in the next version

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the issue was with react. downgrading to React 0.14.8 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this question today. Maybe, it is beacuse you upgrade the React to @15.* version. Downgrade the React to @0.14.8 version, it works!